# CSV text clean up and comparing in Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

Thanks for reading! I am very new to this but yesterday I started extracting data (name of an item and its corresponding price) from websites and figered out how to create csv files in the format : price,item-name for a given website using Python 2.7. Now that I have some sets of data I want to compare them and get an average price for a given item-name. The problem I am encountering now is that the item name (might) slightly differ on each website. For example my first dataset gives the csv file

```
4.0, Jungle Book
5.0, "Peter Pan"
4.0, Lady and the Tramp
```

the second gives

```
5.0, Disney's Jungle Book
6.0, Disney's Up
4.0, Disney's Peter Pan
```

the third gives

```
5.0, Up (DVD)
4.0, Peter pan (DVD)
6.0, "Lady and the Tramp" (DVD)
```

In the end I would like an average output file like

```
4.5, Jungle Book
5.0, Lady and the Tramp
4.33, Peter Pan
5.5, Up
```

My first problem is deleting special characters like " or certain words (eg "Disney's", "(DVD)") that are in my csv file. I find information about deleting rows and columns from csv files but I have a hard time editing inside these elements. Something like this to remove '(DVD)' kind of works but makes my csv file an even bigger mess with more " and [ characters..

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('DesktopData.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('fixformat.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)# dialect='excel')
specials = '(DVD)'

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Once that would work out, I want to take the average price for a given title. I have something in mind but lack the python syntax to really figure it out

```
Read all titles and put in mainlist;
 if title already exsists, ignore/dont make new row with title
Read all files and compare with mainlist;
 if title is found, put corresponding price in new column behind title
```

In my head this has to ouput

```
Jungle Book, 4.0, 5.0
Lady and the Tramp, 4.0, 6.0
Peter Pan, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0
Up, 6.0, 5.0
```

Once I would get this I am pretty sure I can make it into the average csv file. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to take a look into importing pandas and having a play around with it. Start with looking at pd.read_csv() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardest, by far, part of this, is to find what names that are the same, the small differences apart. In the solution here, I have made a simple `normalize_title`function, but it is far from perfect. I guess it needs to be manually tweaked and extended for each new data set. But, appart from that, here is a solution to your problem, that collects the data from several csv files and then stores the average cost together with the movie title in a new csv file:

```
import csv

filenames = ['first.csv', 'second.csv', 'third.csv']
outfile = 'avg.csv'

removables = ['[', ']', '"', "'", "Disney's", '(DVD)']
def nomalize_title(title):
    for remove in removables:
        title = title.replace(remove, '')
    title = title.lower() # Correct capitalization is HARD
    return title

moviecosts = dict()
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            raw_title = row[1]
            title = normalize_title(raw_title)
            price = float(row[0])

            if not moviecosts.has_key(title):
                moviecosts[title] = []

            moviecosts[title].append(price)

with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for movie in moviecosts:
        avg_cost = sum(moviecosts[movie])/len(moviecosts[movie])
        row = [avg_cost, movie]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

As can be seen, I am storing the different costs into a dictionary of lists. To me, this seems to be the most natural data structure for the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just ran it and at the moment it gives me an output of 1 value in 1 cell which is the overall average of all dvd's in the database but this is definitely helpfull. I cannot find a list with the titles after the normalization; as in where can I find the titles in 'movie'?

Comment: If you only get one average, that would imply all titles being 'normalized' to the same string. What do you have if you print the `moviecosts` dict

Comment: If I print moviecosts it displays {None: [4.0, 12.0, ...., 22.0]} So there are no titles saved? In the variable explorer I can see that the raw_title goes up to the last title of the last database though. And all the database prices are in moviecosts

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot to add a return statement in the function normalizing the file names. That will make python default to return `None`. Try with the update I just added. Hopefully that works better.

Comment: The normilization is working fine now, nice! The output however only gives that last csv file input and does not compute with the first and second. I see however that it is working fine averaging as there are some duplicates of a given title in the last database

Comment: That makes no sense to me. The code will loop the files in the `filenames` list, one-by-one. I cannot see how it misses anything. Are you sure that you have copied the example correctly and that the contents of each of the csv files have the same format?

Comment: I re-extracted the data and everything is working like a charm now, can't thank you enough man! Now it's up to me to make my own normilization 'library' for a given website and everything's sound